# Nested linq loops

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, linq.js

Iam trying to iterate the below JSON with linq.js , Here my scenario is I am having an array which contains 3,5,6.Based on this array values i need firstName from below JSON. How can i achieve it . The JSON is just given for an example in real time am handling with 50000 records, what is the best way to achieve this?

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you're trying to do is a join.  A naive approach would simply just do a join.

```
var ids = [ 3, 5, 6 ];
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .Join(ids, "Number($.id)", "$", "$")
    .ToArray();
```

However this wouldn't work out well when there are many objects to work with since you're performing a linear search for the associated items.  You can improve things by creating a lookup of the objects by id.  You'll just have to pay the up front cost of creating the lookup.

```
var lookup = Enumerable.From(data)
    .ToObject("Number($.id)");
var ids = [ 3, 5, 6 ];
var query = Enumerable.From(ids)
    .Select(function (id) {
        return lookup[id];
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Jeff , What if I want to to reverse the question for example I need all the array values except 3,5,6. what I should do for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of that big amount of data would hang other process, make the user feel laggy, you can try this:

```
var process = function(obj, targets, callback, context) {
    // Init context
    var results = [];
    var length = obj.length;
    var procLimit = 500; // Whatever the amount you want to process at a time, higher will have higher change to cause lag on browser.
    context = context ? context : null;

    var current = 0;

    // Loop function
    var looper = function() {
        if (current >= length) {
            callback.call(context, result);
            return;
        }
        var end = Math.min(length, current + procLimit);
        var id, findIndex;
        // Only process a fixed amount of item in a time.
        for (; current < end ; ++current) {
            id = parseInt(obj[current].id, 10);
            findIndex = targets.indexOf(id);
            // Find the matched key, and put to result.
            if (findIndex >= 0) {
              results.push(obj[current]);
              // or you just need fname, use
              // results.push(obj[current].firstName);
              // remove founded from targets
              targets.splice(findIndex, 1);
            }
        }
        current += procLimit;
        // Non-blocking
        setTimeout(looper, 10);
    };

    // Non-blocking
    setTimeout(looper, 10);
};
// Usage
process(YOUR_OBJ, [1, 3, 5, 6], function(processedObj){
  // do somthing with the processed Object
}, THE_CONTEXT);
```

This function will tries to run as in background, and when it complete scan through the json array, it'll call your handler with the founded items in an `array` as `param`.

If block-effect is not in concern, then simply use the filter:

```
var targets = [1, 3, 5, 6];
var filterResult = YOUR_JSON.filter(function(item) {
  var id = parseInt(item.id, 10);
  return (targets.indexOf(id) >= 0);
}).map(function(item) { return item.firstName; });
```